# How to truncate float to %.2f format while encoding it to JSON?

Tags: java, android, json

Let we have some `float f = 52.92;`. In fact, it will hold the value something like `52.91999816894531`. But I want to transmit it to my web-app using json-string truncating those non-significant digits. How would I do this?

As a result, I need to obtain this json string:

```
{"price": 52.92}
```

The code I use:

```
float f = 52.92;
JSONObject js_price = new JSONObject();
js_price.put("price", f);
Log.d("json", js_price.toString());
```

Produces this ugly json:

```
{"price": 52.91999816894531}
```

Also, I need `"price"` to be a number format in json, not a string.

Comment: Why are you using `float` instead of `BigDecimal` for prices in first place? You constantly keep up fixing all those floating point issues whenever the value is to be transferred/manipulated/etc and is been expected in a fixed number format.

Comment: BigDecimal seems to be over-headed for the purposes needed by me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that I can use the constrctor [JSONObject(String json)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29), something like this:

```
JSONObject js_price = JSONObject(String.format("{\"price\": %.2f}", f);
```

and after that I can do with this object any other json-related things...

Answer (score 2):

Try using String.format

`Log.d("json", String.format("%.2f", f));`

Edit:

Is using a float required, or could you try double?

```
    double d = 52.92;
    JSONObject js_price = new JSONObject();
    js_price.put("price", d);
    Log.d("json", js_price.toString());
```

Comment: I should have read your question more carefully. I would suggest using BigDecimal instead of float for currency.

Comment: yep, this (String.format(...)) will not work at all as js_price is not a float...

Comment: double doesn't solve the problem - there will be another value which will result in loooong part after point

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do that with a `JSONObject`.

Since there's no such exact floating point value as `52.92` you really have to use string formatting rules, but then you can't have the JSON encoder treat that value as a number instead of as a quoted string.

You'd have to do:

```
String json = String.format("{\"price\", %.2f }", f);
```

In any event, when the JSON is read back at the client, it *still* won't be `52.92`, it'll be `52.91999816894531` again.  So all you'll have achieved is a small saving in the size of your JSON.

The other alternative would be to multiply the number by 100 and then send it as an integer.  You'll *still* get `52.91999...` when you divide it on the client side, though!

You may also be able to sub-class `JSONObject` and override this method:

```
static public java.lang.String numberToString(java.lang.Number number)
```

Comment: String json is not a simple json object - it is complex object with JSONArray and other stuff... I just trancated all to a minimum information which will show the problem

Comment: @Alnitak : If the OP is using the 'built-in' JSON capabilities of Android then the package will be `org.json` and the docs for `JSONObject` state **"Although this class is nonfinal, it was not designed for inheritance and should not be subclassed."**. Just thought I'd clarify that.

Comment: @Squonk ah, thanks - so much for that idea...  I wonder what they did in the class that breaks inheritance that way...

Comment: @Alnitak : I'm not sure as I've never taken the time to try to find the source code. The docs for all of the classes in that package (except `JSONException`) give the same warning. The `org.json` package seems to have been provided for convenience and is usable but many Android devs choose to use other 3rd-party packages.

Answer (score 0):

Give GSON a try...

```
class Serializer {

// You can register custom serilaizers to it to suite your needs    
private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    public static final <T> String toJSON(T clazz) {
        return gson.toJson(clazz);
    }
}
```

then use the following code to get json string

```
float f = 52.92;
Map<String,Object> js_price = new HashMap<String,Object>()
js_price.put("price", f);
String json = Serializer.toJSON(js_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this utility class with your own parameters :

```
public class BigDecimalUtils {

    /**
     * <code>MathContext</code> with precision 10 for coordinates.
     */
    private final static MathContext MC = new MathContext(10);

    /** Scale for coordinates. */
    private final static int SCALE = 6;

    public static float format(double aDouble) {
        BigDecimal bdLatitude = new BigDecimal(aDouble, MC).setScale(SCALE, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bdLatitude.floatValue();
    }

    public static float format(float aFloat) {
        BigDecimal bdLatitude = new BigDecimal(aFloat, MC).setScale(SCALE, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bdLatitude.floatValue();
    }

}
```

Then just call `js_price.put("price", BigDecimalUtils.format(f));`

Answer (score -2):

You can try this method after deserializable value

```
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("###.##");

System.out.println(dec.format(value));
```

Comment: Float.valueOf(value).floatValue();